# Upgraded from Dotnet Core 2.2 to Dotnet 5. Partials no longer get View Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-2.0, asp.net5

## Original Problem

I'm working on updating a webapp from dotnet core 2.2 to dotnet 5. Most things are working pretty well, but I'm stuck on the partial views.

The website uses a ton of Ajax requests and most return a small partial view with some html. All the variable information in partial was set through the viewdata.

After updating to dotnet 5 the viewdata comes into the partial as empty.

For example, I'm returning a partial "_mailbox". In the controller you can see that I have stuff in the viewdata:

[image]

but when I step into the partial you can see it is blank! In 2.2 it was passed through.

[image]

The basic fuction -

```cs
public ActionResult OnGetGetMailbox(int id)
{
  ViewData["Fullname"] = "Christopher"
  return Partial("_mailbox")
}
```

Do you have any ideas what may have gone wrong? I've basically just followed the steps outlined by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

## How to Reproduce

So I started a brand new project to test and have the same issue -

[image]
[image]

Add a new html partial `_test.cshtml`

[image]

Add a new function in `index.cshtml.cs`

[image]

Then when running the webapp `https://localhost:44332/?Handler=test`

I should see my name-
[image]

But it is blank. When debugging and stepping through I see the viewdata is not passed to the view.

## Other information

- It works in Dotnet Core 2.2.105.
- per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-a-partial-view-in-a-razor-pages-pagemodel) the same syntax as 2.2 should work in 5.1. However, as @Brando Zhang pointed out, you have to use the antiquated syntax from dotnet 2.1 to make this work.
- If you read the docs for the Partial function for dotnet 5 it claims to be part of the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages` namespace, but if you try to use that namespace you will find the `Partial` does not exist. [see docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.razorpages.pagebase.partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[image]

## Is it a bug?

Comment: According to your description, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well. I could get the result. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqD5m.png). Have you tired to create a new .net 5 project and do some test?

Comment: @BrandoZhang thanks for taking the time to do a demo. I created a separate project as well, but didn't pass the partials. Here are links to my startup, project, and .csproj, I wonder how they differed from your? They match closely (except the extra packages) what the default is now! [csproj](https://gist.github.com/christopherpickering/618dbd995d7f58ff4b9b970590e3512e) [startup.cs](https://gist.github.com/christopherpickering/c37050262e42040c077e18ea1f25ddb3) [project.cs](https://gist.github.com/christopherpickering/fb49a2b1b1660e61c0c34598f8f916d4)

Comment: @BrandoZhang I added  steps to reproduce with a fresh demo. Does it do the same for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the return Partial is MVC function result not razor pages, if you want to use razor page's Partial result, you should build by yourself.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
    public IActionResult OnGetTest()
    {

        ViewData["Test"] = "test";
        var partialView = "_test";


        var partialViewResult = new PartialViewResult()
        {
            ViewName = partialView,
            ViewData = ViewData
        };
        return partialViewResult;
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: but if I follow the exact steps to reproduce using the DotNet core 2.2 sdk instead of 3.1 or 5.0 it works :(

Comment: but you are right as well, I suppose this is the only way to make it work in 3.1 and 5. Another win for microsoft lol

Comment: from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-a-partial-view-in-a-razor-pages-pagemodel) it seems that there should have been not change from 2.2 to 3.1 or 5 and the syntax you found to work is from dotnet <= 2.1?